If $T,A\in\mathcal{B(H)}$, $\Vert x\Vert=1$, and $(x\otimes x)T\bot A$, then $A=(I-x\otimes x)S$ for some $S\in\mathcal{B(H)}$.
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $T,A\in\mathcal{B(H)}$. Suppose $P_x=x\otimes x$ is a rank-1 projection satisfying $P_x T\bot A$, i.e., $(P_x T)^*A=0$, then prove that there exits an $S\in\mathcal{B(H)}$ such that $A=(I-P_x)S$.
I don't know how to solve this but I think this is true because $I-P_x$ should be the "largest" operator that's orthogonal to $P_x T$, and thus $A$ should be part of $I-P_x$.

If $P_x \perp A$, then sure, the result is right. But as is, you can just choose a $T$ s.t. $P_xT = 0$, then $A$ can be anything and the result is trivially false.
